# Do Generic Nodes Need to be Part of a Generic List?

Tags: java, generics

I am tasked with creating a class called Node that has instance variables: E data (Generic) and nextNode (singly linked-list implementation). To do that I created a class

```
public class Node<E>
```

and implemented all relevant methods.

I then have to create a List that has instance variables Node head and int size. In essence, the List contains a collection of Nodes. However, I am not sure how if I am supposed to define the class as a generic List or a regular List.

```
public class List<E>
```

vs

```
public class List
```

Which implementation makes more sense and why? Thanks to anyone who can help me understand the concept of generics.

Comment: If you don't provide the type in `List`, what type would you make `Node`(s) in your `List` (and why)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If my nodes contain data of various types, does it matter to the List? I figured that the List only cares about containing nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When to use `List<E>`**

If your list should only support adding elements of one type, use `List<E>`.

For example, you want to be able to create a list of `Integer`s or a list of `Double`s, but not a list that mixes the two.

Then you can support an add and remove interface that uses the generic type `E` in order to enforce the fact that only items of that type and no others can be added.

**When to use `List`**

If your list should support adding items of many different types, use `List`.

For example, if you want to be able to add a `Node<Integer>`, a `Node<Scanner>`, and a `Node<Double>`.

That way you can allow the programmer to add `Node`s of any type they wish, because the list has no type parameter.

**Warning**

The above holds if you are writing your own `List` class (which the question makes it sound like you are). If you are using the built in `java.util.List` class, then you should never use it without a type parameter.

Comment: Only the first half of your answer is correct.  If your list needs to support adding items of many different types, you should use `List<Object>`, or `List` of some other type that is a supertype of everything you want to store.  You should _never_ use `List` without a type parameter.

Comment: @DavidWallace I am aware that we should not use the raw type `java.util.List` without type parameters, but that's not the question OP asked. He is making his own implementation of `List`, and I don't see any reason he can't do so without a type parameter if he wants to accept all objects.